# Is there an equivalent of "Not <Null>" in symbology categories with unique values, many fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I would like to symbolise based on 2 date fields (d1,d2) in a layer. I would like to be able to have 3 different symbols:

1. d2 is NOT null
2. d1 is null AND d2 is null
3. dl is NOT null AND d2 is null

Is this possible at the symbology definition level? Is there a way of specifying a value `<not null>` or `<any other values>` on a per field basis as you can for `<null>`?

Comment: This could be done fairly easily using *labels* with classes, but not on *symbology*. The only way to do it with symbology would be to specify a symbol for null, and then rely on the blanket 'all other values' category for everything else. But that would only work with one field at a time. Both multiple fields and multiple attributes methods leave you with too many values where one is null and the other is unique. The alternative to the new coded value field on which to symbolize is add the layer three times with different global symbol and put a definition query on each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new field and then using 'select by attributes'. Do this for each of your three categories and populate your new field with some common value (ie. 1, 2, or 3). You could then base your symbology on this new field and properly show your three different symbols. Bit of a work around but that is how I would approach this problem.

Comment: OK thanks, I was trying to avoid this, but based on your reply I assume the answer to my question is "No".

Comment: You could use the 'unique values, many fields' option in the symbology tab but you will have to group multiple values together to get your desired result. I believe a new field is a simpler approach.

Comment: Yes, there are many (1000's) different dates so grouping is not an option.